# Get Session using CTools in Pentaho User Console 5.0

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

How do I get a current session value in Pentaho User Console 5.0 that we use to get using Pentaho Action Sequence (.xaction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dashboards.context and then :

Dashboards.context.user, Dashboards.context.roles, ...

Comment: Is it using CDE file?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "CDE file"